# Как заставить работать ihtml?

Tags: php

Залил на сайт, но не понимаю как заставить работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиге апача для выбраного сайта добавить в строку .ihtml:

```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .ihtml
```